# FiWare cloud - connect 2 instances

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

If I have 2 instances on WireCloud:

- One as Business logic / Data Storage porpoise
- Another one as Front end server and hosting web applications.

Both are visible each other through internal IPs (10.0.9.*) or I need a new public / floating IP. If this second case how can I request a new one?

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but they should both have an internal IP you can use to establish a communication between them, so no need to request public IPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make the "Business logic / Data Storage" server publicly available (thought a public IP) as long as all the widgets use the proxy provided by WireCloud for connecting to these services.

Comment: Yes, I did not take in account that servers are visible through the proxy provided. Thanks